# OCI runtime error while executing ML perf object detection benchmark

Tags: python, machine-learning, benchmarking

```
~/mlperf/training/object_detection$ sudo nvidia-docker run -v .:/workspace -t -i --rm --ipc=host mlperf/object_detection "./run_and_time.sh"

docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "./run_and_time.sh": stat ./run_and_time.sh: no such file or directory: unknown.
```

when I am trying to run object_detection , showing above error .

I tried running commands as given in below github link for executing ML perf benchmark.

[https://github.com/mlcommons/training/blob/master/object_detection/README.md](https://stackoverflow.com)

`nvidia-docker run -v .:/workspace -t -i --rm --ipc=host mlperf/object_detection     "cd mlperf/training/object_detection && ./run_and_time.sh"`

while running this in command prompt I got error as below

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "./run_and_time.sh": stat ./run_and_time.sh: no such file or directory: unknown.
```

then executed command by removing "cd mlperf/training/object_detection" from it and then also got same error.

Why is this happening and how to resolve it?